# Noty not defined

Tags: php, laravel, noty

I am trying to install noty to get notifications in my laravel project, but it doesn't seem to be working, I always get that Noty is not defined, I have tried everything and don't really know what to do, any solution?

**Instalation :**

[image]

**App.scss :**

[image]

**Bootstrap.js :**

[image]

**app.blade.php :**

[image]

**Error :**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Noty is not defined

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: load order perhaps? try debug `window.Noty` before that `new Noty` call, its most likely not there

Comment: if i put this in the chrome console `new Noty({
    type: 'success',
    layout: 'topRight',
    text: 'Some notification text', time: 200
}).show();` it works just fine.

Comment: well that would be explained by the load order wouldnt it? When you type it in the console, you are running it at a later time than the script above

Comment: Alright, i fixed it by adding a window.onload function but what is other way around this? Where could i have declared the noty?

Comment: well it appears bootstrap.js is loaded after your script tag. Or there is some sort of wrapper code around it which is not shown above. So simply make sure the order of execution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding a window.onload function

Answer (score -1):

try add run this when you want to test :

```
npm run dev
```